# keeping three divs inline

Tags: html, css

I have three divs wrapped within a container. Within each div there is an image and text below it. I want to keep all three divs side by side and responsive. I had this set up before where it stayed how I wanted it, but now the right div falls under the other two when the screen shrinks and then the middle one falls. I know I can keep all three side by side because I've done it before. I just can't figure out how I did it.

html

```
<div id='container'>

    <div class='one-third'>
        <a><img src='http://gratisography.com/pictures/264_1.jpg'><h3>Headline</h3></a><p>Medieval texts date the arrival of the Vikings in the British Isles to the 790s A.D., when fierce raiders from Scandinavia suddenly appeared along the coasts, plundering rich monasteries and terrorizing local communities. </p>
    </div>

    <div class='one-third'>
        <a><img src='http://gratisography.com/pictures/264_1.jpg'><h3>Headline</h3><p>Medieval texts date the arrival of the Vikings in the British Isles to the 790s A.D., when fierce raiders from Scandinavia suddenly appeared along the coasts, plundering rich monasteries and terrorizing local communities. </p>
    </div>

    <div class='one-third'>
        <a><img src='http://gratisography.com/pictures/264_1.jpg'><h3>Headline</h3><p>Medieval texts date the arrival of the Vikings in the British Isles to the 790s A.D., when fierce raiders from Scandinavia suddenly appeared along the coasts, plundering rich monasteries and terrorizing local communities. </p>
    </div>

    <div>
```

CSS

```
.one-third  {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5% 0 0 2.5%; }

.one-third img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px; }

.one-third h3 {
    margin: .5em 0 2em 0; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It didn't help that you had an unclosed `<a>` tags and I advise that you do not set a height on the `<img>`, unless you want the image to distort when scaling the viewpoint. But to address the issue that you've asked for, it can be resolved simply by:*

- Changing: `display: inline-block` to `display: block` in `.one-third {}`
- Adding: `float: left;` in `.one-third {}`
- [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SimonHayter/fnum86n9/2/) here for you

*Corrected code:*

```
.one-third  {
    max-width: 30%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5% 0 0 2.5%; 
}

.one-third img {
    width: 100%;
}

.one-third h3 {
    padding: 0.5em 0 2em 0;
}

<div id='container'>
    <div class='one-third'>
        <a>
            <img src='http://gratisography.com/pictures/264_1.jpg'>
            <h3>Headline</h3>
        </a>
        <p>Medieval texts date the arrival of the Vikings in the British Isles to the 790s A.D., when fierce raiders from Scandinavia suddenly appeared along the coasts, plundering rich monasteries and terrorizing local communities. </p>
    </div>
    <div class='one-third'>
        <a>
            <img src='http://gratisography.com/pictures/264_1.jpg'>
            <h3>Headline</h3>
        </a>
        <p>Medieval texts date the arrival of the Vikings in the British Isles to the 790s A.D., when fierce raiders from Scandinavia suddenly appeared along the coasts, plundering rich monasteries and terrorizing local communities. </p>
    </div>
    <div class='one-third'>
        <a>
            <img src='http://gratisography.com/pictures/264_1.jpg'>
            <h3>Headline</h3>
        </a>
        <p>Medieval texts date the arrival of the Vikings in the British Isles to the 790s A.D., when fierce raiders from Scandinavia suddenly appeared along the coasts, plundering rich monasteries and terrorizing local communities. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Simon, your JSFiddle works how I want it to. But when I run it through Sublime, the divs slowly slide down. I do have a bottom section underneath this and there's section over it as well. Not sure if this has anything to do with it. Because of the float I've had to clear:both for the bottom section so it doesn't creep up the page. Any ideas of why your code works and my code (exactly like yours) doesn't?

Comment: Most likely because of the margins of your template, cant say much more without seeing the rest of the code or the website.

Comment: Simon, I did a clear:both on the container as well and that seemed to solve the problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to be working as you expect, see below.

If you shrink your page enough, eventually the width of the word "Headline" in `h3` will be greater than 1/3 of the page width, which will then force the inline-block elements to start wrapping.

If you tried using CSS tables, you could keep all three items on a single line but then you would trigger an overflow condition.

You need to think about how you want your layout to behave in the extreme, narrow case.

```css
.one-third {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5% 0 0 2.5%;
}
.one-third img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.one-third h3 {
  margin: .5em 0 2em 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>

  <div class='one-third'>
    <a>
      <img src='http://gratisography.com/pictures/264_1.jpg'>
      <h3>Headline</h3>
    </a>
    <p>Medieval texts date the arrival of the Vikings in the British Isles to the 790s A.D., when fierce raiders from Scandinavia suddenly appeared along the coasts, plundering rich monasteries and terrorizing local communities.</p>
  </div>

  <div class='one-third'>
    <a>
      <img src='http://gratisography.com/pictures/264_1.jpg'>
      <h3>Headline</h3>
    </a>
    <p>Medieval texts date the arrival of the Vikings in the British Isles to the 790s A.D., when fierce raiders from Scandinavia suddenly appeared along the coasts, plundering rich monasteries and terrorizing local communities.</p>
  </div>

  <div class='one-third'>
    <a>
      <img src='http://gratisography.com/pictures/264_1.jpg'>
      <h3>Headline</h3>
    </a>
    <p>Medieval texts date the arrival of the Vikings in the British Isles to the 790s A.D., when fierce raiders from Scandinavia suddenly appeared along the coasts, plundering rich monasteries and terrorizing local communities.</p>
  </div>

  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the `.one-third` rule. This also takes care of the inclusion of margins and padding into the overall width of an element.

Answer (score 0):

Set the parent's `font-size` to 0, and then 'reset' the childs back to its previous size. For a demo, I have set the divs to exactly 33% of the parent each:

```css
.one-third {
  width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0%;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.one-third img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.one-third h3 {
  margin: .5em 0 2em 0;
}
#container {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>

  <div class='one-third'>
    <a>
      <img src='http://gratisography.com/pictures/264_1.jpg'>
      <h3>Headline</h3>
    </a>
    <p>Medieval texts date the arrival of the Vikings in the British Isles to the 790s A.D., when fierce raiders from Scandinavia suddenly appeared along the coasts, plundering rich monasteries and terrorizing local communities.</p></a>
  </div>

  <div class='one-third'>
    <a>
      <img src='http://gratisography.com/pictures/264_1.jpg'>
      <h3>Headline</h3>
      <p>Medieval texts date the arrival of the Vikings in the British Isles to the 790s A.D., when fierce raiders from Scandinavia suddenly appeared along the coasts, plundering rich monasteries and terrorizing local communities.</p></a>
  </div>

  <div class='one-third'>
    <a>
      <img src='http://gratisography.com/pictures/264_1.jpg'>
      <h3>Headline</h3>
      <p>Medieval texts date the arrival of the Vikings in the British Isles to the 790s A.D., when fierce raiders from Scandinavia suddenly appeared along the coasts, plundering rich monasteries and terrorizing local communities.</p>
</a>     
 </div>

  <div>
```

<sup>Credits need to go to @Marc Audet for further noticing your `<a>` tags need to be closed for correct HTML markup.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add a `float: left;` to `.one-third`

Here is a working JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/05x1p2ch/

Comment: Let's not "just add a float" property into the mix. This would cause more problems than it would solve.

Answer (score 0):

Remove spaces between divs:

```
<div id='container'>

    <div class='one-third'>
        <a><img src='http://gratisography.com/pictures/264_1.jpg'><h3>Headline</h3></a><p>Medieval texts date the arrival of the Vikings in the British Isles to the 790s A.D., when fierce raiders from Scandinavia suddenly appeared along the coasts, plundering rich monasteries and terrorizing local communities. </p>
    </div><div class='one-third'>
        <a><img src='http://gratisography.com/pictures/264_1.jpg'><h3>Headline</h3><p>Medieval texts date the arrival of the Vikings in the British Isles to the 790s A.D., when fierce raiders from Scandinavia suddenly appeared along the coasts, plundering rich monasteries and terrorizing local communities. </p>
    </div><div class='one-third'>
        <a><img src='http://gratisography.com/pictures/264_1.jpg'><h3>Headline</h3><p>Medieval texts date the arrival of the Vikings in the British Isles to the 790s A.D., when fierce raiders from Scandinavia suddenly appeared along the coasts, plundering rich monasteries and terrorizing local communities. </p>
    </div>

    <div>
```

Or use float property.